# BigQuery Dashboard Design - Cost Optimization And Caching

Tags: caching, database-design, redis, google-bigquery, dashboard

I have to design Dashboard with data source in bigquery.

Dashboard should be giving 3 graphs and tables

1. Table- Total payments to purchase and date wise breakage.
2. Two row table/ pie chart basically showing the done payment and pending payment.
3. Last and the biggest one showing bar chart total sales and redeemed aggregated

a. Day wise for last 30 days

b. Week wise for last 12

c. Month wise for last 6

Now I want to ask about 3 really, not the UI, that was for completeness.

Design 1. Create date wise tables from joining the dumps of all the services and application tables ( we have microservices) as a schedule Job in merchant bff. And then use the query cache of bigquery. And bigger aggregate from those tables.

Design 2. Run the schedule Job but don't create date wise tables and load that data then in redis cache for front-end.

I am in kind of fix bent more toward Design 1. But have reasons and few doubts.

1. Assumption is that bigquery query cache is good and better than redis is it?
2. Still in Design 1 there will be two queries one load and one select, so is my choice wrong? And Design 2 is better?
3. Did I miss anything in Design 1 if it's the one I should pursue. One thing I kind of noticed while writing down the solution is I haven't taken into account merchant ID in the date table design schema.
4. Is redis unnecessary moving part/ complexity here.
5. My data is not PETA byte big data but I hope it will be.

Comment: @jordan-tigani can you please help me here

Comment: This is beyond the scope of what would constitute an [appropriate question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for Stack Overflow. This seems more like a list of requirements you have been expected meet and are deferring to the community. Should you have any specific questions about how some components of BigQuery work or how to accomplish one specific task, I would suggest asking in such a way that the community can attempt to answer succinctly. In addition, it's somewhat difficult to understand what you seek without sample data and an example of the view you are hoping to get.

Comment: @Nicholas Thanks! But IMHO don't think that its inappropriate. The Question might be long but I specifically mentioned in it that I am looking on a specific point. And to me still its very much google-bigquery + design problem. May be if you want to move it some sub stack exchange (may be architects / design) but I don't know if I will get rid of  google-bigquery  even there.

Comment: In order to help, we would really need some more specifics. Perhaps you can provide an example of the raw data and the outcome you're looking for. Or otherwise more specific questions about BigQuery functionality, features and expected behaviors.